# Applying VBA to any row

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to write a script where if anything in columns F to KA changes, column D of the same row is cleared.

I have the following script:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
If Not Intersect(Target, Range("F7:KA7")) Is Nothing Then
    Range("D7").ClearContents
End If
End Sub
```

This clears content from a specific cell (column C) if anything in that row changes. I'd like it to apply to any row where it's always column D that is cleared where anything in F to KA changes.
I though it would be straightforward but can only get it to change D7 where anything in any row changes, instead of column D in the edited row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use the Target to indicate which row(s) you need to change, added a for-loop to do it for multiple rows in case you're changing more than one cell at once.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim rng As Range, ccell
    Set rng = Intersect(Target, Range("F:KA"))
    If Not rng Is Nothing Then
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        For Each ccell In Intersect(rng, Target.Cells(1, 1).EntireColumn)
            Range("D" & ccell.Row).ClearContents
        Next ccell
        Application.EnableEvents = True
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Was just about to add to my answer the `For Each ccell` bit in case more than one cell was changed.  You beat me to it. :)

Comment: No time like the present ;) @DarrenBartrup-Cook

Answer (score 1):

`Target` is a reference to the cell you're changing, so you just need to grab the row from that reference.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("F1:KA1").EntireColumn) Is Nothing Then
        Application.EnableEvents = False 'Stop the Change event firing when column D is cleared.
            Cells(Target.Row, 4).ClearContents
        Application.EnableEvents = True
    End If
End Sub
```